# Wow6432Node subkeys inaccessible from 64 bit registry view

Tags: c#, .net, registry, regedit

I am writing a program that traverses the registry. When encountering the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`-Key, the program stops because

```
var openedKey = key.OpenSubKey(/* any name of the present (!) subkeys*/);
// where "key" is "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node"
```

yields `null`.

Therefore, I tried to find this key using `regedit.exe` and `reg.exe` and the result was that there are indeed subkeys that can be seen using this methods. Furthermore,

```
key.GetSubKeyNames()
```

returns the exact same values for the names.

I tried compiling for 64- and 32-bit CPUs and passed both `RegistryView.Registry32` and `RegistryView.Registry64` to the first

```
RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(hive, view)
```

call.
This did not solve the problem.

Why are the returned keys `null`?

Comment: Avoid HKCR, it is fake.  Use HKCU\Software\Classes\VirtualStore instead.

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean by "fake"? What makes the "fakeness" of this keys?